# Visual Studio 2015 no item templates

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, localdb

In Visual Studio 2015 when I wanted to add LocalDb (by SQL Server Database item) from templates I discovered that they're gone.

There isn't any Data templates and what's more strange, there aren't any Online templates to download.

I'm using stable VS 2015 with:

- Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools [v.14.0.x]

I also have installed on my machine all Sql Server packages distributed with Visual Studio 2015.

#### Question

How can I restore/add those missing item templates?

#### Already checked:

- Calling `devenv /installvstemplates` to restore default templates didn't work
- I've got all templates files in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\ItemTemplates` directory

---

Add new item - Installed node
[image]

Add new item - Online templates node

[image: Add New Item window]

Comment: Did you check under the "Installed" item in the tree view? Should be Installed>Visual C#>Data

Comment: Yes, I have only DNX item templates in "installed" node as you can see on the first screen. 
They're should be there, and those item templates are even in correct directory as I mentioned.

Comment: Sorry, I missed the indent because of the circle. Have you tried a full repair installation on Visual Studio?

Comment: Not yet, but I'm afraid that is how it will end.

Comment: It's my own question which I'd like to close because:

* no answer was provided and I don't think that there would be any answer for this
* even I abandon searching for answer and simply used newer distribution of VS later
* the problem doesn't occurs on newer distributions of VS

Answer (score 4):

I registered just to answer this question because this problem occurred to me with the latest visual studio 2015 update 3. I searched the whole internet and couldn't find a solution, until I found it in the most obvious place.

To solve this: In the command prompt navigate to "Visual Studio Installation Path\Common7\IDE"

and type this: devenv /installvstemplates

Source: [Microsoft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms247116(v=vs.100).aspx)

Comment: Just for info you should run this command as administrator or else it won't work

Answer (score 0):

Mid 2017 and still there are no online templates to be found - in any category, for VS2015.

Very annoying.